# jQuery: How to add name on the file when exporting table to excel

Tags: jquery, excel

I have this code on exporting table to excel. It works fine. So my question is how to change the name of the file when downloading?

```js
$('#export').click(function() {
  window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('#toexcel').html()));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="export">Export to Excel</a>
<div id="toexcel">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('#export').click(function() {
  window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('#toexcel').html()));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="export" download="hello">Export to Excel</a>
<div id="toexcel">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

you can specify a filename using the download attribute, but this is not widely supported: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Comment: Not supported in any version of Safari or Internet Explorer (or Edge) yet http://caniuse.com/#search=Download [June, 2015]